# Lock Sharing Between Classes

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am trying to find the best practice for sharing a lock file between multiple classes. Before this I was putting multiple functions inside the same class, so they could share a mutual lock file and a producer/consumer queue. The code is getting a bit longer than I'd like, and I want to break them up into individual classes. When I do this I am unable to share the lock files, or the queues to add/remove the commands from.

I need to have a UI thread that accepts input from the user, and then places the commands into a locked queue that the worker threads can pull from. I would like to place the UI thread and the worker functions into different classes to keep my code nicely organized.

Sorry if this is too vague. Is there a way to do this that doesn't break good design technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the locks are shared between multiple classes, and the "owner" is not readily identifiable, then place those locks into a class that is shared.

```
public class MyLocks { ... all your locks ... }
```

Then when you initialize your classes that utilize the locks, pass them into the constructor.  Alternatively, you can have the classes instantiate MyLocks on their own, and then expose it as a property which you can then use in subsequent construction.

```
...
var a = new ClassWithLocks();
var b = new ClassWithLocks(a.MyLocks);
var b = new SomeOtherClassWithLocks(a.MyLocks);
...
```

The takeaway is to place the locks into their own unit.

**Update**

An additional benefit of placing multiple locks into their own class is that you can explicitly create methods for seizing and releasing locks.  For example:

```
void PushLock(string myToken, LOCK_ENUM theLockIWant);
void PopLock(string myToken, LOCK_ENUM theLockIWant);
```

Now a particular class or operation can request locks, but if they try to grab a lock whose enumerator is less than the lock they are requesting, you can throw an exception.  This is important when you require multiple locks to perform an operation as you can ensure that the locks are seized and released in order, which is one of the most common culprits in deadlocks.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of using, but read that passing lock files around in such a manner wasn't good design.. I think that for a project where the only thing being locked is a work queue, this wouldn't be much of a problem though.

Comment: If two classes are so tightly coupled that they know of each other's locks, then they are effectively operating as a single testable unit.  There are tricks to hide the implementation of the locks from the public through interfaces and nested classes, but it might be overkill.  In practice, I minimize the number of locks needed by creating a WorkItem, which I submit to a queue.  The queue is consumed by a single thread which calls out to the submitter when it's his turn, and avoids the need for the callback function to seize any locks at all.  It all depends on what you are doing, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the thread safe ConcurrentQueue from the System.Collection.Concurrent namespace and share this queue between your UI thread and the worker threads like so:

```
ConcurrentQueue<T> workItems = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();

UIThreadClass uiThread = new UIThreadClass(workItems);

WorkerThreadClass workerThread = new WorkerThread(workItems);

uiThread.Run();

workerThread.Run();
```

In your worker thread class you could periodically check the work item queue
for new items by using the method TryPeek(). For a detailed description on the
ConcurrentQueue refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd267265.aspx).

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What's a 'lock file'? Are you using the FileStream [Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock.aspx) / Unlock methods? If so, you might consider whether you really need them.

Back to locking: I think that a simple, shared,  [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx)([Slim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx)) should do in most cases (and yours). Michael outlined the basic idea - you should add a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) on top of that - it would simplify your project and life a lot (no need to pass the instance around, easier to debug).

Take care with those threads, deadlocks are not fun!

PS: It might be obvious (to some) but locks are only effective when dealing with multiple threads.

Comment: Sorry I meant a lock variable, such as 
readonly object workLock = new object();

Comment: Thank you.  Seeing your comment on deadlocks reminded me that a centralized class allowed one to be more deliberate when troubleshooting locks -- specifically allowing a person to acquire locks in order and only release in that order.